# Missing session cookie in consent redirect request error from MS OAuth

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, microsoft-teams

I am implementing a Microsoft Teams tab extension. The backend must query the Graph API, and for this I need additional consent from the user for the `User.Read` permission. This is how I try to request it inside the frontend part:

```
import * as msTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js';

// ...

const args = {
  client_id: '<client_id>',
  response_type: 'code',
  state: '12345',
  prompt: 'consent',
  scope: 'openid https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read',
  nonce: new Date().valueOf().toString()
};
const url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?' + getQuery(parts);

await msTeams.authentication.authenticate({
  url: url,
  width: 600,
  height: 535
});
```

The dialog pops up, I select the user, review permissions request and click accept, but then an error is returned:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "Missing session cookie (consent12345) in consent redirect request."
  }
}
```

I have tried a lot of parameter combinations, and none seem to work. What is the reason for this error?

Comment: The error message "Missing session cookie (consent12345) in consent redirect request" indicates that there is an issue with the consent redirect request. This error typically occurs when the session cookie, which is used to track the user's consent, is missing.

To resolve this error, you need to ensure that the session cookie is included in the consent redirect request. The session cookie is typically generated and stored when the user gives consent for accessing a Microsoft Graph resource.

Comment: For more information on handling consent requests and managing cookies in your app, you can refer to the Microsoft Teams platform documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad?tabs=teamsjs-v2#handle-consent-redirect-request